# how to join two same queries with one different condition without using union

Tags: mysql

```
select date_format(FROM_UNIXTIME(employee.inserted_time), "%X-%V") as Week, count(employee.id) as managers
from jobs
join dept on jobs.id = dept.id
join employee on jobs.id = employee.id and employee.salary > 10000
where employee.status ='rejected' or 'cancelled' 
group by Week;

select date_format(FROM_UNIXTIME(employee.inserted_time), "%X-%V") as Week, count(employee.id) as employees
from jobs
join dept on jobs.id = dept.id
join employee on jobs.id = employee.id and employee.salary > 10000
where employee.status ='accepted' or 'working' 
group by Week;
```

Total_jobs = (managers+employees)/managers

I have the two queries which are almost same but with one different condition employee.status. I want to fetch the result as managers and employees and need to calculate the Total_jobs all in a single query

Comment: Show us sample data with expected output.

Answer (score 1):

Use conditional aggregation:

```
SELECT
    DATE_FORMAT(FROM_UNIXTIME(e.inserted_time), '%X-%V') AS Week,
    COUNT(CASE WHEN d.status in ('rejected', 'cancelled') THEN e.id END) AS managers,
    COUNT(CASE WHEN d.status in ('accepted', 'working') THEN e.id END) AS employees
FROM jobs j
INNER JOIN dept d ON j.id = d.id
INNER JOIN employee e ON j.id = e.id AND e.salary > 10000
GROUP BY Week;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `CASE` inside a `SUM()` to do this in a single query. For example:

```
select
  date_format(FROM_UNIXTIME(employee.inserted_time), "%X-%V") as Week,
  sum(case when employee.status in ('rejected', 'cancelled') then 1 else 0 end) 
    as managers
  sum(case when employee.status in ('accepted', 'working') then 1 else 0 end)
    as employees
from jobs
join dept on jobs.id = dept.id
join employee on jobs.id = employee.id and employee.salary > 10000
where employee.status in ('rejected', 'cancelled', 'accepted', 'working')
group by Week
```